# How can I draw a solid square in BlackBerry?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I'm making a BlackBerry OS 6+ application and I need to draw a solid square of a specific color (given at runtime) **but it should be add-able to a** `VerticalFieldManager`. So I *think* custom-drawing using a `Graphics` object is not an option.

I already tried setting the background color of a `LabelField` to the color I want and adding that `LabelField` to the `VerticalFieldManager`. To get the square-shaped appearance, I tried overriding the `getPreferredWidth()` and `getPreferredHeight` of `LabelField` to return a higher value (eg: 150). But although the width was correctly displayed, the height stayed the same no matter what value I returned.

So is there any way I can achieve this? In summary, what I want is:

- A solid square-shaped block of color (color decided at runtime).
- Which should be added to a `VerticalFieldManager`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927472/thick-border-for-rounded-button-in-blackberry/8928025#8928025

Comment: @alishaik786 No, I want pure-solid square-shaped something... It needn't have any listeners or behavior. Only for displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code , Pass in the color in the constructor.

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;

public class CustomField extends Field
{

private int backgroundColour; 
private int fieldWidth;
private int fieldHeight; 
private int padding = 8;

public CustomField(int color)
{
    super(Field.FOCUSABLE); 
    fieldHeight = 100;
    fieldWidth = 100;
    this.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    this.backgroundColour=color;
} 

public int getPreferredWidth()
{
    return fieldWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight()
{
    return fieldHeight;
}

protected void layout(int arg0, int arg1)
{
    setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
}

protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on)
{

} 

protected void paint(Graphics graphics)
{
    graphics.setColor(backgroundColour);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, fieldWidth, fieldHeight); 
}
}
```

Comment: Works nicely! Thanks a lot for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();

    Field f = new Field() {

        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
            graphics.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
        }

        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            setExtent(200, 200);
        }
    };
    vfm.add(f);

    add(vfm);
```